# Conversions Between STL and Hana tuples

Tags: c++, boost-hana

```
#include <boost/hana.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

namespace hana = boost::hana;

int main()
{
    int x{7};
    float y{3.14};
    double z{2.7183};
    auto t = hana::to<hana::tuple_tag>(std::tie(x, y, z));
    hana::for_each(t, [](auto& o) { std::cout << o << '\n'; });
}
```

What's the hana way of accomplishing this?  I realize I can use: `hana::make_tuple(std::ref(x), std::ref(y), std::ref(z))`, but this seems unnecessarily verbose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To convert between a `hana::tuple` and a `std::tuple`, you need to make `std::tuple` a valid Hana sequence. Since `std::tuple` is supported out-of-the-box, you just need to include `<boost/hana/ext/std/tuple.hpp>`. Hence, the following code works:

```
#include <boost/hana.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/ext/std/tuple.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
namespace hana = boost::hana;

int main() {
    int x{7};
    float y{3.14};
    double z{2.7183};
    auto t = hana::to<hana::tuple_tag>(std::tie(x, y, z));
    hana::for_each(t, [](auto& o) { std::cout << o << '\n'; });
}
```

Note that you can also use `hana::to_tuple` for less verbosity:

```
auto t = hana::to_tuple(std::tie(x, y, z));
```

That being said, since you're using `std::tie`, you probably want to create a `hana::tuple` containing references, right? That is not possible right now, see [this](https://github.com/boostorg/hana/pull/179#issuecomment-139915710) for the reason. However, you can simply use `std::tuple` in `hana::for_each`, provided you include the adapter header above:

```
#include <boost/hana.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/ext/std/tuple.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
namespace hana = boost::hana;

int main() {
    int x{7};
    float y{3.14};
    double z{2.7183};
    auto t = std::tie(x, y, z);
    hana::for_each(t, [](auto& o) { std::cout << o << '\n'; });
}
```